# Multiple JSON Objects in AS3 Socket

Tags: json, sockets, actionscript-3

I've got a Socket coming back with this JSON from a camera

```
      var string:String = socket.readUTFBytes(socket.bytesAvailable);

      string = '{"rval":0,"msg_id":514}{ "msg_id": 7, "type": "video_record_complete" ,"param":"/tmp/fuse_d/DCIM/100MEDIA/YDXJ0149.mp4"}';
```

i.e. 2 JSON objects in the socket.

Is there any way to split them before decoding?

This is the JSON decode error I get when I try and decode them

```
JSONParseError: Unexpected characters left in input stream
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to split them before decoding?

Sure, just use `split()`:

```
var strings:Array = string.split("}{");
```

However, you can probably just extract each JSON message one at a time using `readtUTF()` instead of `readtUTFBytes()` with all `bytesAvailable`:

```
while (socket.bytesAvailable) {
    var json:String = socket.readUTF();
}
```